# Does FullCalendar require a CDN to work (in ServiceNow)?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have been implementing the FullCalendar in ServiceNow with one big issue.
It seems that the FullCalendar only works when I use the external CDN Link as a depedency or script tag src on my widget.

Any method of hosting the .js file on ServiceNow seems to break the calendar, causing errors and breaking functionality. Be it, using Script includes or a link to the .js file hosted in ServiceNow either in a script tag or as a dependency.

Is it required for the calendar to work that I use an external CDN instead of being able to host it locally?
After much debate with ServiceNow Support, they seem to think that this might be the issue instead of their way of implementing hosted files.

Comment: What specific errors are you getting? Are the hosted files in question not loading into the browser properly? What HTTP response code do you get for those in the Network tool? There's no specific requirement to host anything on a CDN AFAIK. The browser/fullCalendar doesn't actually know/care where the script files were loaded from, once they're up and running. You could try and resolve the specific errors you're receiving in your environment, but we don't know what they are unless you mention them.

Comment: @ADyson Hi, thanks for the advice. The file itself loads without issues. I can see it in the Network Tab that it has loaded the full minified js.
If I for example change views, I get the following error: "properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')". It seems like it can't find some functions in the file for some reason.

Comment: In that case, it sounds more like maybe you have the wrong version of something. FullCalendar requires more than one file to be loaded potentially, depending on the technique you've used (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getting-started). It might help if you showed your code. You can [edit] your question. P.S. The only times I've ever heard people mention that error is in connection with ReactJS. Does your solution involve React?

Comment: @ADyson I've checked that before, it requires only that one file if you use a script tag. It works with only that one file if I just use an external CDN instead of the ServiceNow one. I even tried hosting that singular file on my own CDN and that also worked. You can see how I'm certain it must be an issue with ServiceNow, which according to their "Dev Team" is not the case.

Comment: ServiceNow doesn't control what happens in the browser, though. So unless their server is injecting extra content into your page which is then contributing to the error, it's hard to see what the issue could be from their side. Either it's not loading the expected version of the file, or something else is in the mix, or something like that. It would help _us_ to understand the scenario more clearly though, and start to be able to rule certain things out, if you provided a [mre] of the issue in your question. Actual code is always much better than just a description of the code!

Comment: Can you give some direction on how to get the CDN to work on the service portal, this is where I'm stuck.

The latest version I've been able to embed in a ui script is 3.10.

Comment: @Dwaine if you have question, please ask one. Comments are not searchable, and are not seen by the whole community (I only noticed this because I had previously "followed" this question). You'll also need to supply some more meaningful detail about what you've tried with later verions, and what went wrong. You can provide a link back to this post and quote from it, if you think something from it might be relevant to yours. See also [ask]. Thanks.